# VBA Userform Entry 1st time of entry name adds 01 at end of name 01 then 2nd adds 02

Tags: vba, series, userform, countif

Howdy I am trying translate the the following code in Excel to VBA userform entry modifier:

For Example, I know how to code all of the columns below except for column C in VBA.

```
Name    Individual ID   Unique ID   First Name  Last Name   ID#
Charles Robol   CharlRobol  CharlRobol01    Charles Robol   01
Charles Robol   CharlRobol  CharlRobol02    Charles Robol   02
Charles Robol   CharlRobol  CharlRobol03    Charles Robol   03
Charles Robol   CharlRobol  CharlRobol04    Charles Robol   04
Charles Robol   CharlRobol  CharlRobol05    Charles Robol   05
Charles Robol   CharlRobol  CharlRobol06    Charles Robol   06


 =B4&TEXT(COUNTIF($B$2:$B4,$B4),"00")
```

The B Column is essentially different unique values where 01 is added to the first time the value comes up then 02 and so fourth. The point of this function is to facilitate determining if an entry is original or not and if not original, then I want the userform to automatically have the values associated with the preceding entry of the same name.

I know that I can either do:

1. translate the count if function above into a VBA combobox code/rowsource?/controlsource? (most ideal because then guaranteed that the entry properly updates in the userform
2. Somehow reference a cell where Excel logic uses the above function where say, the excel function is in (Sheet1! ActiveCell.Row, 3)

I obviously don't understand VBA and excel logic and syntax to be able to figure this stuff out without just studying general VBA coding until I solve the problem on my own.

Any help is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the sort of thing that would be better to handle in Access, but I realize that you are probably more interested in an Excel solution.  You actually can directly convert that formula to VBA because you can call the worksheet functions via `Application.WorksheetFunctions` like so:

```
Range("C4") = Range("B4") & Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B2:B4"), Range("B4")), "00")
```

I leave it as an exercise for you to wrap the code in a function and generalize it to apply to your situation, but if you run into trouble drop a comment.